# Knocking back the Player in a Unity 2D TopDown Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When something hits the Player, maybe an enemy or spikes etc., I want him to get knocked back in the oppisite direction of the enemy.

So what I already got:

```
public void ChangeHealth(float healthToAdd, Vector2 objectPosition) // Change the players health, objectPosition = enemies position or something else
    {
        if (healthToAdd < 0) // incoming damage
        {
            // ... other stuff

            Knockback(objectPosition);
        }

        // ... other stuff
    }

    void Knockback(Vector2 objectPosition) // Knockback routine
    {
        Vector2 knockbackPosition = new Vector2( , ); // calculation is missing here! Calculate the new position by the knockback direction

        rigid.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(playerPos, knockbackPosition, 2 * Time.deltaTime)); // the knock back
    }

    private void Update() // !! TEST !!
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) // TEST routine
        {
            ChangeHealth(-7, new Vector2(10,10)); // decrease players health by 7 and knock him back
        }
    }
```

And what is missing:

```
Vector2 knockbackPosition = new Vector2( , );
```

I am looking for a calculation like this picture is showing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vector2 knockbackPosition = 
    transform.position + (transform.position - objectPosition).normalized *a
```

---

To understand why is it equal to that you have to read through.

There are three points: E,P,K (Enemy, Player, Knockback)

And one scalar number: a (the greater this value is, the more knockback you'll have)

---

Now from your picture:

`PK = EP*a`

expand vectors into distances between two points:

`(K-P) = (P-E)*a`

calculate the location of K:

`K = P + (P-E)*a`

There is one problem though. (thanks to Rotem) with this formula as it is:

> you'd expect a bigger knockback from a closer opponent.

We don't want the knockback to be dependent on the distance between P and E.

> To remove the dependency on the former, normalize the vector before multiplying by a

So we add `.normalized` to use just the **direction** of (P-E) instead of its **original vector**

Comment: The way you currently have it is that the length of the knockback vector is dependent on the distance between the two players *and* the variable `a`. This is counter-intuitive because if anything, you'd expect a bigger knockback from a *closer* opponent. To remove the dependency on the distance, normalize the difference vector before multiplying by `a`.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem I almost missed that.