# How to do knock-backs in PyOpenGL with object facing?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am making a game in PyOpenGL and I want to apply knock-back on camera when an object is close enough. A knock-back is simply putting the camera backward according to the enemy facing direction.

I've modeled this on a piece of paper and found out

```
xc = person.pos[0] - camera_pos[0]
yc = person.pos[1] - camera_pos[1]
zc = person.pos[2] - camera_pos[2]
glTranslatef(xc,zc,yc) #my z and y are flipped due to gluLookAt()
```

but it doesn't seem to be working and I want to work with the facing of the object, not relationships between x, y and z.

Also, I've tried the [Knocking back the Player in a Unity 2D TopDown Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168790/knocking-back-the-player-in-a-unity-2d-topdown-game) solution:

```
xc,yc,zc = normalize([(camera_pos[0] + (camera_pos[0] - person.pos[0])) * 5,(camera_pos[1] + (camera_pos[1] - person.pos[1])) * 5,(camera_pos[2] + (camera_pos[2] - person.pos[2])) * 5])
glTranslatef(xc,zc,yc)
knockback = False
```

But somehow I can control how am I knocking back if I turn the perspective (e.g. if I face left I will be knocked back to the left).

Full code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

import math,sys,numpy,random,ctypes

pygame.init()
display = (1500, 900)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1])
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1])

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
gluLookAt(0, -8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
glTranslatef(0,-8,0)
viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
glLoadIdentity()

# init mouse movement and center mouse on screen
displayCenter = [screen.get_size()[i] // 2 for i in range(2)]
mouseMove = [0, 0]
pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter)

cmddown = False
cam_attack = False
cam_damage = random.randint(20,30)
knockback = False
person_count = 1
up_down_angle = 0.0
camera_pos = (0,0,0)
paused = False
run = True
#xzy = xyz

#Functions & Classes
def InverseMat44(mat):
    m = [mat[i][j] for i in range(4) for j in range(4)]
    inv = [0]*16

    inv[0]  =  m[5] * m[10] * m[15] - m[5] * m[11] * m[14] - m[9] * m[6] * m[15] + m[9] * m[7] * m[14] + m[13] * m[6] * m[11] - m[13] * m[7] * m[10]
    inv[4]  = -m[4] * m[10] * m[15] + m[4] * m[11] * m[14] + m[8] * m[6] * m[15] - m[8] * m[7] * m[14] - m[12] * m[6] * m[11] + m[12] * m[7] * m[10]
    inv[8]  =  m[4] * m[9]  * m[15] - m[4] * m[11] * m[13] - m[8] * m[5] * m[15] + m[8] * m[7] * m[13] + m[12] * m[5] * m[11] - m[12] * m[7] * m[9]
    inv[12] = -m[4] * m[9]  * m[14] + m[4] * m[10] * m[13] + m[8] * m[5] * m[14] - m[8] * m[6] * m[13] - m[12] * m[5] * m[10] + m[12] * m[6] * m[9]
    inv[1]  = -m[1] * m[10] * m[15] + m[1] * m[11] * m[14] + m[9] * m[2] * m[15] - m[9] * m[3] * m[14] - m[13] * m[2] * m[11] + m[13] * m[3] * m[10]
    inv[5]  =  m[0] * m[10] * m[15] - m[0] * m[11] * m[14] - m[8] * m[2] * m[15] + m[8] * m[3] * m[14] + m[12] * m[2] * m[11] - m[12] * m[3] * m[10]
    inv[9]  = -m[0] * m[9]  * m[15] + m[0] * m[11] * m[13] + m[8] * m[1] * m[15] - m[8] * m[3] * m[13] - m[12] * m[1] * m[11] + m[12] * m[3] * m[9]
    inv[13] =  m[0] * m[9]  * m[14] - m[0] * m[10] * m[13] - m[8] * m[1] * m[14] + m[8] * m[2] * m[13] + m[12] * m[1] * m[10] - m[12] * m[2] * m[9]
    inv[2]  =  m[1] * m[6]  * m[15] - m[1] * m[7]  * m[14] - m[5] * m[2] * m[15] + m[5] * m[3] * m[14] + m[13] * m[2] * m[7]  - m[13] * m[3] * m[6]
    inv[6]  = -m[0] * m[6]  * m[15] + m[0] * m[7]  * m[14] + m[4] * m[2] * m[15] - m[4] * m[3] * m[14] - m[12] * m[2] * m[7]  + m[12] * m[3] * m[6]
    inv[10] =  m[0] * m[5]  * m[15] - m[0] * m[7]  * m[13] - m[4] * m[1] * m[15] + m[4] * m[3] * m[13] + m[12] * m[1] * m[7]  - m[12] * m[3] * m[5]
    inv[14] = -m[0] * m[5]  * m[14] + m[0] * m[6]  * m[13] + m[4] * m[1] * m[14] - m[4] * m[2] * m[13] - m[12] * m[1] * m[6]  + m[12] * m[2] * m[5]
    inv[3]  = -m[1] * m[6]  * m[11] + m[1] * m[7]  * m[10] + m[5] * m[2] * m[11] - m[5] * m[3] * m[10] - m[9]  * m[2] * m[7]  + m[9]  * m[3] * m[6]
    inv[7]  =  m[0] * m[6]  * m[11] - m[0] * m[7]  * m[10] - m[4] * m[2] * m[11] + m[4] * m[3] * m[10] + m[8]  * m[2] * m[7]  - m[8]  * m[3] * m[6]
    inv[11] = -m[0] * m[5]  * m[11] + m[0] * m[7]  * m[9]  + m[4] * m[1] * m[11] - m[4] * m[3] * m[9]  - m[8]  * m[1] * m[7]  + m[8]  * m[3] * m[5]
    inv[15] =  m[0] * m[5]  * m[10] - m[0] * m[6]  * m[9]  - m[4] * m[1] * m[10] + m[4] * m[2] * m[9]  + m[8]  * m[1] * m[6]  - m[8]  * m[2] * m[5]

    det = m[0] * inv[0] + m[1] * inv[4] + m[2] * inv[8] + m[3] * inv[12]
    for i in range(16):
        inv[i] /= det
    return inv

def touched(tar_x,tar_y,tar_z,tar_x1,tar_y1,tar_z1):
    centerPt = pygame.math.Vector3(tar_x,tar_y,tar_z)
    point2 = pygame.math.Vector3(tar_x1, tar_y1, tar_z1)
    distance = centerPt.distance_to(point2) 
    return distance

def follower(x,y,z,x1,y1,z1,speed):
    dir_x, dir_y = (x1-x, y1-y)
    distance = math.hypot(dir_x, dir_y)
    dir_x, dir_y = (dir_x/distance, dir_y/distance)
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(dir_y, dir_x)) + 90
    return (dir_x*speed, dir_y*speed, 0, angle)

def random_pos(max_distance):
    x_value_change = random.randrange(-max_distance + 2,max_distance + 2)
    y_value_change = random.randrange(-max_distance + 2,max_distance + 2)
    z_value_change = 0
    return (x_value_change, y_value_change, z_value_change)

def blit_text(x,y,font,text,r,g,b):
    blending = False 
    if glIsEnabled(GL_BLEND):
        blending = True
    glColor3f(r,g,b)
    glWindowPos2f(x,y)
    for ch in text:
        glutBitmapCharacter(font,ctypes.c_int(ord(ch)))
    if not blending:
        glDisable(GL_BLEND) 

def subtract(v0, v1):
    return [v0[0]-v1[0], v0[1]-v1[1], v0[2]-v1[2]]
def dot(v0, v1):
    return v0[0]*v1[0]+v0[1]*v1[1]+v0[2]*v1[2]
def length(v):
    return math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0]+v[1]*v[1]+v[2]*v[2])
def normalize(v):
    l = length(v)
    return [v[0]/l, v[1]/l, v[2]/l]

# Ray - Sphere intersection
#
# Sphere:       dot(p-C, p-C) = R*R   `C`: center, `p`: point on the sphere, `R`, radius 
# Ray:      p(t) = A + B * t     `A`: origin, `B`: direction        
# Intersection:   dot(A+B*t-C, A+B*t-C) = R*R
#             t*t*dot(B,B) + 2*t*dot(B,A-C) + dot(A-C,A-C) - R*R = 0
def isectObj(p0, p1, C, R):
    A = p0 #Origin 
    B = normalize(subtract(p1, p0)) #Direction
    oc = subtract(A, C) 
    a = dot(B, B)
    b = 2 * dot(oc, B)
    c = dot(oc, oc) - R*R
    discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c
    if discriminant > 0:
        t1 = (-b - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a)
        t2 = (-b + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*a)
        t = min(t1, t2)
        return t if t >= 0.0 else None
    return None

class Ground:
    def __init__(self,mul=1):
        self.vertices = [
        [-20,20,-1],
        [20,20,-1],
        [-20,-300,-1],
        [20,-300,-1]
        ]

    def draw(self):
        glBegin(GL_QUADS) #Begin fill
        for vertex in self.vertices:
            glColor3f(0,0.5,0.5)
            glVertex3fv(vertex)
        glEnd()

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertices = [
            [-1,0,1],
            [-1,0,-1],
            [1,0,-1],
            [1,0,1],
            [-1,1,1],
            [-1,1,-1],
            [1,1,-1],
            [1,1,1]
        ]

        self.vertices = list(numpy.multiply(numpy.array(self.vertices),1))
        self.edges = (
            (0,1),
            (0,3),
            (0,4),
            (1,2),
            (1,5),
            (2,3),
            (2,6),
            (3,7),
            (4,5),
            (4,7),
            (5,6),
            (6,7)
            )
        self.surfaces = (
            (0,1,2,3),
            (0,1,5,4),
            (4,5,6,7),
            (1,2,6,5),
            (0,3,7,4),
            (2,3,7,6)
            )
        self.x = self.vertices[1][0]
        self.y = self.vertices[1][2]
        self.z = self.vertices[1][1]
        self.pos = (self.x,self.y,self.z)
        self.rot = 0
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = random.randint(20,40)
        self.level = 1

    def draw(self):
        glTranslated(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.pos[2])
        glRotated(self.rot,0,0,1)

        glBegin(GL_QUADS) #Begin fill
        for surface in self.surfaces:
            for vertex in surface:
                glColor3f(0,1,0)
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()
        glLineWidth(5) #Set width of the line
        glBegin(GL_LINES) #Begin outline
        for edge in self.edges:
            for vertex in edge:
                glColor3f(1,1,0)
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
        glEnd()

    def move(self,x,y,z):
        self.pos = (self.pos[0]+x,self.pos[1]+y,self.pos[2]+z)

glutInit()
persons = [Person() for person in range(person_count)]
ground = Ground()
for person in persons:
    person.pos = random_pos(12)
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused = not paused
        if not paused:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                mouseMove = [event.pos[i] - displayCenter[i] for i in range(2)]
                pygame.mouse.set_pos(displayCenter)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    cam_attack = True

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    if not paused:
        #Get keys
        keypress = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        #Init model view matrix
        glLoadIdentity()

        #------------------------View------------------------
        #Apply the look up and down (with 90° angle limit)
        if up_down_angle < -90:
            if mouseMove[1] > 0:
                up_down_angle += mouseMove[1]*0.1
        elif up_down_angle > 90:
            if mouseMove[1] < 0:
                up_down_angle += mouseMove[1]*0.1
        else:
            up_down_angle += mouseMove[1]*0.1
        glRotatef(up_down_angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        #Init the view matrix
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()

        #Apply the movement 
        if keypress[pygame.K_w]:
            glTranslatef(0,0,0.1)
        if keypress[pygame.K_s]:
            glTranslatef(0,0,-0.1)
        if keypress[pygame.K_d]:
            glTranslatef(-0.1,0,0)
        if keypress[pygame.K_a]:
            glTranslatef(0.1,0,0)

        if knockback:
            #Knockback
            xc,yc,zc = normalize([(camera_pos[0] + (camera_pos[0] - person.pos[0])) * 5,(camera_pos[1] + (camera_pos[1] - person.pos[1])) * 5,(camera_pos[2] + (camera_pos[2] - person.pos[2])) * 5])
            glTranslatef(xc,zc,yc)
            knockback = False

        #Apply the look left and right
        glRotatef(mouseMove[0]*0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        #------------------------View------------------------

        #Multiply the current matrix by the new view matrix and store the final view matrix 
        glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)
        viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
        invVM = InverseMat44(viewMatrix)
        camera_pos = (invVM[12],invVM[13],invVM[14])

        #Apply view matrix
        glPopMatrix()
        glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)

        #Get current view matrix, projection matrix and viewport rectangle 
        mv_matrix = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
        proj_matrix = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
        vp_rect = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)

        #Calculate "near" and "far" point 
        pt_near = gluUnProject(displayCenter[0], displayCenter[1], 0, mv_matrix, proj_matrix, vp_rect)
        pt_far  = gluUnProject(displayCenter[0], displayCenter[1], 1, mv_matrix, proj_matrix, vp_rect)

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, [1, -1, 1, 0])

        #Follow, attack
        crosshair_color = (1,1,1)
        attacklist = []
        for person in persons:
            freturn = follower(person.pos[0],person.pos[1],person.pos[2],camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2],0.02)
            xchange,ychange,zchange = freturn[0],freturn[1],freturn[2]
            person.rot = freturn[3]
            if (touched(person.pos[0],person.pos[1],person.pos[2],camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2])) < 2.5:
                xchange,ychange,zchange = 0,0,0
                knockback = True
            person.move(xchange,ychange,zchange)
            if (touched(person.pos[0],person.pos[1],person.pos[2],camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2])) < 5 and isectObj(pt_near, pt_far, person.pos, 1) != None:
                crosshair_color = (1,0,0)
                if len(attacklist) >= 2:
                    bigger = attacklist[1] > touched(person.pos[0],person.pos[1],person.pos[2],camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2])
                    if bigger == True:
                        attacklist = [person,touched(person.pos[0],person.pos[1],person.pos[2],camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2])]
                else:
                    attacklist = [person,touched(person.pos[0],person.pos[1],person.pos[2],camera_pos[0],camera_pos[1],camera_pos[2])]
        if attacklist:
            if cam_attack == True:
                attacklist[0].health -= cam_damage

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        #Draw crosshair, health 
        blit_text(displayCenter[0] - 5,displayCenter[1] - 5,GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,"+",crosshair_color[0],crosshair_color[1],crosshair_color[2])
        for person in persons:
            if person.health > 0:
                #print(person.health)
                pass

        glPushMatrix()

        glColor4f(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1)
        for person in persons:
            glPushMatrix()
            person.draw()
            glPopMatrix()

        ground.draw()
        glPopMatrix()

        for person in persons:
            if person.health <= 0:
                persons.remove(person)

        cam_attack = False
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I expected to be knocked back no matter how I rotate the view, but I can change where I am knocking back if I rotate the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "knock back direction is the direction from the current position (`camera_pos`) to the object (`person.pos`). Calculate the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) of this direction (the length of the unit vector is 1):

```py
knockback_dir = normalize(subtract(person.pos, camera_pos))
```

Do not calculate a new position by adding a vector to the camera position (`camera_pos`), because [`glTranslatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) does that for you. It creates a new matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix, so the translation is relative to the current translation.

Scale the direction by a certain distance (`knockback_dist`). The vector has to be applied to the camera in world space, this means after the view matrix was set:

```
viewMatrix = viewMatrix * knockBackTranslation
```

The distance of the object to the camera has to be increased, so the vector has to be added to the object. Note, the view space position of the eye (camera) is always (0, 0, 0). What has to be changed is the the scene (all the objects) in relation to the camera.

```py
#Multiply the current matrix by the new view matrix and store the final view matrix 
glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)

if knockback:
    knockback_dist = 10
    knockback_dir = normalize(subtract(person.pos, camera_pos))
    glTranslatef(knockback_dir[0]*knockback_dist, knockback_dir[1]*knockback_dist, 0)
    knockback = False
```

[image]

Comment: It is correct, but my view changes whenever I got a knock-back, which is not I want. How can I change that?

Comment: Also, if I face backward (not seeing the mesh) I will be knocked back toward the mesh (even though I was going backward, but I faced the other way), not forward. I want a knock-back based on object.